# How can I continue with the execution of the loop without terminating the function early with the use of python decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like the loop to continue to execute until the end after each error is handled (6 to 9). Now it seems to terminate mid execution at i == 6. I'm using a decorator for error handling. What did I do wrong here?

```
class SomeError(Exception):
    pass

def do_something_helper(number: int) -> bool:
    if number > 5 and number < 10:
        raise SomeError(f"Some kind of error")
    else:
        return True

def do_nothing(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except SomeError as e:
            print("Handle the error")
    return wrapper
@do_nothing
def do_something_main(number: int):
    for i in range(0, number):
        print(i)
        if do_something_helper(i):
            print("Next")
        else:
            print("Something's wrong")

do_something_main(20)
>>
    0
    Next
    1
    Next
    2
    Next
    3
    Next
    4
    Next
    5
    Next
    6
    Handle the error
```

Comment: Move the try/catch to be the first/topmost thing inside the loop. That way, the catch prevents it ever breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `do_nothing` essentially wraps the entire `do_something_main` function in a try block. As soon as an exception is raised, the entire function's execution is stopped. Although the exception is handled, that is after it has already propagated out of the `do_something_main` function.

If you instead decorate `do_something_helper` with `@do_nothing`, then the loop will continue through all the iterations since the exception is immediately handled without having the chance to leave the `do_something_main` function.